# mod_fcgid process doesn't respawn

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have a Python script running on my server as a FastCGI using Apache2 and mod_fcgid. I let it spawn up to five processes. But I soon get messages like these in the Apache logs:

```
[Wed Sep 02 23:16:34 2009] [warn] (103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
[Wed Sep 02 23:16:35 2009] [warn] (103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
```

and then Apache doesn't seem to recognize that all its processes are dead (I have a max of 5 backends) and refuses to spawn new ones:

```
[Wed Sep 02 23:26:16 2009] [notice] mod_fcgid: /var/www/hacks.og.theinfo.org/picker.fcgi total process count 5 >= 5, skip the spawn request
[Wed Sep 02 23:26:17 2009] [notice] mod_fcgid: /var/www/hacks.og.theinfo.org/picker.fcgi total process count 5 >= 5, skip the spawn request
```

at which point it refuses to respond to requests from the outside world. This doesn't seem to happen with my other FastCGIs, which all use the same Apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  AddHandler    fcgid-script .fcgi
  IPCConnectTimeout 20
  MaxProcessCount 5
  DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 2
  DefaultMinClassProcessCount 1
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what causes it?

Answer (score 1):

[First google hit](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=537922) indicates it might be a Debian bug.